# whats is the meaning of 'if [ -s filename]' in shell?

Tags: shell

So I've 'if [ -s $fname ]' in my shell program.Can someone please tell me what it does? I searched it but there is nothing about '-s'.

```
if [ -s $fname ]
then 
   echo -e "\tname\tph\t\tcity\tpin\tstate"
  cat $fname
else
  echo -e "\nfile is empty"
 fi
;;
```

this is part of my code where -s is used in case you need it.Thanks!

Comment: That would depend on which of the many available shells you are using.

Comment: You need to improve your searching skills
https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/46660-explanation-if-filename.html

This means if the file exists and bigger than 0 bytes

Comment: and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

Comment: @Alex yup..thnx for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the answer in your question itself :-)

`-s $fname` expression evaluates to `True` if the file in variable `$fname` exists and is not empty. So if the `$fname` file is not present or is empty, then your else block will be activated and the code snippet with print `file is empty`

few examples,

```
fname="test.txt"

## case when the file is not existing
if [ -s $fname ]
then 
   echo -e "case-1: $fname exists and is not empty"
  cat $fname
else
  echo -e "case-1: $fname do not exists or is empty"
fi

## case when the file exists but is of empty size
touch $fname

if [ -s $fname ]
then 
   echo -e "case-2: $fname exists and is not empty"
  cat $fname
else
  echo -e "case-2: $fname do not exists or is empty"
fi

## case when the file exists and is having contents too
echo "now its not empty anymore" > $fname

if [ -s $fname ]
then 
   echo -e "case-3: $fname exists and is not empty"
   cat $fname
else
  echo -e "case-3: $fname do not exists or is empty"
fi
```

Output is,

```
case-1: test.txt do not exists or is empty
case-2: test.txt do not exists or is empty
case-3: test.txt exists and is not empty
now its not empty anymore
```